# how to solve the problem occuring in loading the dotenv

Tags: node.js, dotenv

my dot env is not working properly i used port 3000 earlier for a different project it is working properly for tha project only and showing error in new project[[[[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/D5Qps.png)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wugJD.png)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/M9f41.png)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/I4kR7.png)

i tried everything to fix this but the issue is not resolving please to solve this error

Comment: It does not seem to be a dotenv problem. This '9000;' file you created or was created when you started the project? (if is a problema is the ";" key after the "9000")